# Inner join in spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to join two files 10 GB each and using inner join. In my cluster there are 3 worker nodes.

Here is my configuration

```
Driver Memory: 5G
Executor Memory: 15 G
Cores/Executor: 1
spark.cores.max: 9
```

Both files are joining on the basis of ID column. There are 10 millions of records in each file.

Its taking never ending time.

Can anyone please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options:

1. Re-partition data
2. Fix [skewed data issue](https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/optimize-the-skew-in-spark-e523c6ee18ac) if exists
3. set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (otherwise it will create [200](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) partitions by default)
4. Update Spark Configuration (considering one node is of - 15G RAM)
   and 9 Cores

```
Driver Memory: 2G
Executor Memory: 7G
cores: 4
```